# Web scraping data tables to excel

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from a site to excel. right now it's working fine but when it searches someone like Sergio Rodriguez, multiple names come up (https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q=Sergio+Rodriguez), so it skips the name and throws out "No international table for Sergio Rodriguez." How do I select the one that played in the NBA from that list and continue on with scraping the per game and advanced stats tables to excel? in this case, rodriguez is second when you search his name.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


playernames=['Carlos Delfino', 'Sergio Rodriguez']

result = pd.DataFrame()
for name in playernames:

    fname=name.split(" ")[0]
    lname=name.split(" ")[1]
    url="https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q={}+{}".format(fname,lname)
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')


    try:
        table1 = soup.find('h2',text='International Regular Season Stats - Per Game').findNext('table')
        table2 = soup.find('h2',text='International Regular Season Stats - Advanced Stats').findNext('table')

        df1 = pd.read_html(str(table1))[0]
        df2 = pd.read_html(str(table2))[0]

        commonCols = list(set(df1.columns) & set(df2.columns))
        df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=commonCols)
        df['Player'] = name

    except:
        print ('No international table for %s.' %name)
        df = pd.DataFrame([name], columns=['Player'])

    result = result.append(df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

cols = list(result.columns)
cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
result = result[cols]
result.to_csv('international players.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: It looks like you can know that it's the second row because the NBA column is not empty. You will have to iterate over the candidates of a search and make sure you have the most likely one. There aren't many classes, ids, or much structure to the table. It will be difficult.

Comment: ya, i also thought about the nba column, but i'm not too sure how to do it so i thought i should ask

Comment: I you paste the relevant html into your question you will get more help. People are reluctant to check out a random url. If they can answer your question without leaving the page your odds of a solution are greater. It is not obvious to me how to solve this. Good luck!

Comment: what exactly am i supposed to put besides the link?

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL of the page you receive, a search which results in a single match directs you to

```
https://basketball.realgm.com/player/{player-name}/Summary/{player-id}
```

but when there is more than one result you get

```
https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q={player-name}
```

Write a parser function for both urls, such as (pseudocode)

```
...
for name in playernames:
    fname=name.split(" ")[0]
    lname=name.split(" ")[1]
    url="https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q={}+{}".format(fname,lname)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    # check the response url
    if (response.url == "https://basketball.realgm.com/search..."):
        # parse the search results, finding the players you want
        ... get urls from the table ...
        soup.table...  # etc.
        foreach url in table:
            response = requests.get(player_url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
            # call the parse function for a player page
            ...
            parse_player(soup)
    else: # we have a player page
        # call the parse function for a player page, same as above
        ...
        parse_player(soup)
    ...
```

There's a small amount of code duplication, but while you get your head around it and make it work don't worry about that.

Comment: i see the logic but i'm not sure how to write it. also, would this not just record the tables of all the players in the list?

Comment: Yes, it would record all the players in the list. You would need to know some additional information to select the correct player. What else do you know that is shown in the results table? Position, birth date, draft year? Anything which will help uniquely identify the player you want.

Comment: well you can see that the nba column is empty if the player was not in the nba, so if the column is not empty, that's the player i would want. but again, i don't know how to write it.

Comment: i'm pretty new to all this so apologies

Comment: "so if the column is not empty, that's the player i would want"  but what happens if there is the situation where two players with the same name have both been in the NBA? (I've no idea if that would happen, but it's not impossible)

Comment: so there really isn't any other way to go about it besides recording all of them? unless there is a completely different idea?

Comment: I would worry about finding the player data you need after you get the parser working. Or, as a completely different approach, find the player ID of all the players you are interested in (the ones where more than one player is retuned when searching) and feed that information in to your parser instead. Then you don't have to deal with parsing the search results page.